# Как проитерировать объект и получить на выходе новый с Object.keys()

Tags: javascript

У меня есть на входе объект, как вернуть на выходе измененный объект на основе сущствующего?

Я использовал для этого `Object.keys()` в связке с итератором `map()`... Но что-то не работает, на выходе получаю `unefined`

```js
    let objjjj = {
     a: 2,
     b: 3,
     c: 4
    }
    
    console.log(
        Object.keys(objjjj).map((key, i) => 
            { 
       key: objjjj[key] + 1
         }
        )
    )
```

Comment: какой в итоге результат должен быть?

Answer (score 0):

- Создаём пустой итоговый объект
- Берём ключи исходного объекта (по условию, с помощью `Object.keys`)
- Для каждого ключа в итоговый объект добавляем этот ключ со значением, равным значению из исходного объекта плюс единица

Итоговый код:

```js
let objjjj = { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 };
let result = {};
Object.keys(objjjj).forEach(key => { result[key] = objjjj[key] + 1; });
console.log(result);
```

---

Что не так с `map` в исходном коде:

- В `{ key: objjjj[key] + 1 }` фигурный скобки воспринимаются не как создание нового объекта, а как границы тела стрелочной функции. Возвращать объект нужно как `{ return { key: objjjj[key] + 1 }; }`
- Однако тогда имя ключа воспримется как "key", а не как значение `key`. Поэтому нужно сделать `[key]:`
- В итоге получается массив объектов, в каждом из которых по одному ключу-значению из исходного объекта. Нужно объединять их в один объект (например, с помощью связки `reduce` и `Object.assign`)

Итоговый код:

```js
let objjjj = { a: 2, b: 3, c: 4 };
let result = Object.keys(objjjj).map(key => {
    return { [key]: objjjj[key] + 1 };
}).reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, cur), {});
console.log(result);
```